# get the id of the table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with id 'myrequest' and each row have a id in `<td>`.I want to check the value is is clicked from myRequest table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.viewPopLink', function() {
    if ($(this).parent("table").has("[id^='myRequest']").length > 0) {
      // alert('request table');
      console.log('request table');
    } else {
      // alert('approval table');
      console.log('approval table');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myRequest'>
  <thead>
    <th>request ID</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">1819AM0047</td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">1819AM0048</td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">bbb</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to get the `id` of the parent `table` when clicking the `td`?

Comment: Split your event handlers into more specific cases: `$(document).on('click', 'table.myRequest .viewPopLink', ...`

Comment: Although you probably just want to change `($(this).parent("table")` to `($(this).closest("table")`

Comment: closest table also get approval table in console

Comment: *"also get approval table"* - that will happen if you have a nested table (which is unclear from your HTML), in which case your logic would need to be the other way.  If the tables are not nested, then it's not possible and you must have used `.closest()` incorrectly. It depends on which actually *is* the closest.   Using `$(this).parent()` will only give you the parent of the event target, in this case the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution

Use `closest` instead of `parent` and then look for the attribute `attr` (id)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.viewPopLink', function() {
    if ($(this).closest("table").attr("id") === "myRequest") {
      // alert('request table');
      console.log('request table');
    } else {
      // alert('approval table');
      console.log('approval table');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myRequest'>
  <thead>
    <th>request ID</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">1819AM0047</td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">1819AM0048</td>
      <td class="request-edit viewPopLink">bbb</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: @user3386779 Change the IF condition to `if ($(this).closest("table").attr("class") === "myTable myRequest")`

Answer (score 0):

you can bind event on "viewPopLink" like this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".viewPopLink").on("click", function() {
         if ($(this).closest('table').attr('id') == "myRequest") {
            console.log('request table');
         } else {
            console.log('approval table');
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: OP is using event delegation, most likely because the content is generated dynamically.  So this method to "bind the event" will likely not work (in OP's case), and if it did, that part of the event binding would have no impact (the other change you made may,  but it's not in your text/notes)

Answer (score 0):

inside document ready function write this code.
console.log("id ",$('#myRequest').attr('id'));